# Find a div with the class using mink and behat

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

I have a button in the page :

```
<div class="button wide green attached connectyourself" >Conect</div>
```

I want tu push on this div, so I create the methode :

```
/**
 * @When I open the connection popup
 */
public function iOpenTheConnectionPopup()
{
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    $findName = $page->find("css", '.connectyourself');
    if (!$findName) {
        throw new Exception('connectyourself' . " could not be found");
    } else {
        $findName->click();
    }
}
```

Every time I get the exception 'connectyourself could not be found'.
Can you help me please ?

Comment: Your check if the element was found is not correct, `find` returns an object or null so you should use `=== null` instead of `!$findName` also check if your selector returns a single element and finally maybe you need some wait, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911114/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-press-on-a-non-object/42925010

Comment: as @lauda mentioned, please check your if statement, and consider waiting for the element before searching for it.  Finally, you might refine your CSS selector to div.connectyourself

Answer (score 0):

I think this css is not unique. Might be there are more elements with the class name containing "**connectyourself**". You should try finding it by giving a full class nam.

```
$findName = $page->find("css", '.button.wide.green.attached.connectyourself');
```

Comment: @user7424312, have you tried at least to search same error on google . before paste the comment.